# akka-http error: could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller

Tags: spray-json, akka-http

I know that has been asked already, but I can't seem to find an answer.
Here is my code :

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

final case class Client(clientId:Int, clientName:String, platformIds:Int, host:String, password:String)

object ClientJson extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
    implicit val clientFormat = jsonFormat5(Client)
}

class HTTPListenerActor extends Actor with ImplicitMaterializer with RoadMap {

implicit val conf = context.system.settings.config
implicit val system = context.system
implicit val ec = context.dispatcher


Await.result(Http().bindAndHandle(roads, "interface", 8080), Duration.Inf)

override def receive:Receive = Actor.emptyBehavior
}

trait RoadMap extends Directives  {

val roads: Route = path("client"/IntNumber) { id =>
    import ClientJson._
    post {
        entity(as[Client]) { c => complete {c} }
    }
  }
}
```

This code generates error

```
 [ant:scalac] /Users/smalov/Workspace/api-service/src/main/scala/com/acheron/HTTPListenerActor.scala:51: error: could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[com.acheron.Client]
 [ant:scalac]           entity(as[Client]) { c =>
```

Now the most common cause for this kind of error is forgetting to import marshalling implicit into the scope near the `roads` definition, however, I did not forget this. Another reason could be that I have implicit `FlowMaterializer` in scope instead of `ActorMaterializer`, but `ImplictMaterializer` trait takes care of this.

Anything else I could be missing ?

I'm using Scala 2.11.7, Akka 2.3.11, akka-http 1.0, spray-json 1.3.2

Answer (score 17):

I too got the same error and it resolved after importing

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
```

May be this will help

Comment: Note that you'll need to import `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.5"` for `SprayJsonSupport` to be in scope. That being said, it didn't solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Import these things.

```
import spray.json.RootJsonFormat
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
```

Then have this in scope when you call `entity(as[Client])`

```
implicit val clientJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[Client] = jsonFormat5(Client)
```

The conventional way to have it in scope is to have these in a trait, e.g.

```
trait MyJSON extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol with NullOptions {
    implicit val clientJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[Client] = jsonFormat5(Client)
}
```

Then, you mix that into the object that contains your web routes, thus:

```
object MyWeb extends MyJSON {
    val myRoute = 
        get {
            path("client") {
                complete(Future successful Client(...))
            }
        } ~ post {
            path("client") {     
                entity(as[Client]) { client =>
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appeared I needed `ActorMaterializer` in scope in `RoadMap` trait. So, adding `implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer` there solved the compilation problem.

I wish that error were a bit more descriptive ....