# AKKA HTTP(scala) cannot handle Json Array after I upgrade from scala 2.12 to 2.13.8

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, scala-2.13

I've been researching for days about this problem.

I was upgrading scala version of my project from 2.12.15 to 2.13.8, in the meantime I upgraded `spray-json` from 1.3.4 to 1.3.6. `akka-http-spray-json` is still 10.2.7.

Within building there are multiple places that have errors, all of them are related `as[List]`, the code is like:

```scala
var route: Route =
    (path("test-path") & post) {
        entity(as[List[MyCaseClass]]) { reqs =>
          ......
          ......
```

The error showed:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[List[MyCaseClass]]
```

I saw the akka-http source code has no change logs about it, also scala 2.13.x has no change logs about it. Why does `as` suddenly not accept List type, not accept `Seq` or `Array` also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [akka-http error: could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663732/akka-http-error-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-um-akka-http-scala)

Comment: @0x263A Thanks, but I don't think it can solve my issue. I've already tried their solutions but didn't work. The key to my issue is, that only the `List` of something cannot be unmarshalled, I don't know why.